# I want to declare a uniform array without specifing it's size in one shader object while declaring it at another

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Suppose the following shader:

```
uniform float input[]
float do_stuff(int index) {
    return input[index];
}
```

This code does something using some data without caring the size of `input`. **But**, the program will be linked with another shader, that will know the size and invoke it:

```
void do_stuff(int);

uniform float input[3];
void main() {
    gl_FragColor = vec4(do_stuff(input[0]),
                        do_stuff(input[1]),
                        do_stuff(input[2]),
                        1);
}
```

Obviously, this code is stupid, I just created it demonstrate what I need. My real situation is: the data that the "do stuff" shader access is not predefined, each "do stuff" shader will have it owns data. Also, the "do stuff" shader can not know how many times it will be called, so its input are arrays with undefined size. On the other side, the "caller" shader will be generated in runtime, it knows exactly which data the "do_stuff" shaders will use and how many.

Actually, the "do stuff" shaders are user provided, while the "caller" shader mix them together.

So, with a bit of preprocessing on the "do stuff" shader I may solve my problem using parameters, but it will make a bit more complicated for me (because each "do stuff" shader would have a different function signature). If I could just create these undefined size uniform it would be easier.

Also, I am open to suggestions...

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish with this concept of "do stuff"? What problem are you ultimately trying to fix?

Comment: @NicolBolas , at the first two paragraphs I wrote a code, exemplified what I was trying to do. The others paragraph I (though) summarized my problem: I have some processing that the user creates, this processing needs it owns data type. This processing will be used by some "instances", each instance fills the data, but note that the number of instances is unknown for the user that wrote the shader. My problem is that I do not want to recompile the user shader every time the number of instances changes. Anyway, just a "no, it is not a valid glsl" answer will be enough.